# what is the difference between reference function and normal function in PHP5.3?

Tags: php, oop, function

hi I am a php developer.

Recently I got an old project using php5 which I have to upgrade to PHP5.3.

In old version of php5 coding they declare functions in two different ways

```
public function &getMyname(){

}
```

Some other place they are defining like normal

```
public function getMyname(){

}
```

What is the difference between these two declarations.

Comment: Is this question answers yours? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957584/how-does-operator-work-in-php-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method will return by reference.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php