# PHP Explode Array returns text 'Array'

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm using a breadcrumb script for it's obvious use, and I am trying to remove `&anyqueryafterhere` from the result. I'm using for each to go through the array to remove this, but it returns 'Array'. The code I have is

```
if(empty($breadcrumbs)===false){
    foreach($breadcrumbs as &$r){
        $r = explode("&", $r);  
    }
}
```

Currently, it, as mentioned before, just returns `Array`, so it shows as something like `Array » Array`. So first question, what's the cause of this, and second, how can I sort it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You realize that is only going to return the last $breadcrumbs right? You're overwriting $r with each iteration of the foreach loop. (that is after you remove that & from the foreach of course)

Comment: How exactly is he modifying anything in the above code? Other than overwriting $r of course.

Comment: He is overwriting `$r` by reference. In PHP, his line: `$r = explode("&", $r)` is the same as `$breadcrumbs[$key] = explode("&", $r)`. He is modifying the source array because it is being passed *by reference*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Replace

```
foreach($breadcrumbs as &$r){
```

#### With:

```
foreach($breadcrumbs as $r){
```

Remove the `&`.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
foreach($breadcrumbs as &$r){
                        ^-----is reference operator ..remove this Those are references, they are similar to "pointers" in C or C++. 

foreach($breadcrumbs as $r){
```

and

```
if(empty($breadcrumbs)===false){
```

better approach will be

```
 if(!empty($breadcrumbs)){...}
```

**Good Read**

[How does “&” operator work in PHP function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957584/how-does-operator-work-in-php-function)