# Add a key and value into an array via function

Tags: php

My PHP is quite basic when it comes to functions. I am trying to add a key and value pair to an already existing array via a function. 'Oranges' should also appear in the printed array. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
function add_fruit($ar) {
    $ar[] = 'oranges';
}

$fruits = [
    '0' => 'apples',
    '1' => 'pears',
    '2' => 'bananas',
];

add_fruit($fruits);

print_r($fruits);
```

Comment: `$ar` is passed to your function as a _copy_, you will not be changing the original outside of the function with this. Either pass the parameter by reference (careful, with the necessary destruction of the reference afterwards, to avoid unwanted side effects), or have your function return the modified array, and then call it as `$fruits = add_fruit($fruits);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it [by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957584/how-does-the-operator-work-in-a-php-function#:%7E:text=The%20%26%20operator%20tells%20PHP%20not,array%20instead%20of%20a%20copy.) with the code you have just adding `&` to the param:

```
function add_fruit(&$ar) {
    $ar[] = 'oranges';
}

$fruits = [
    '0' => 'apples',
    '1' => 'pears',
    '2' => 'bananas',
];

add_fruit($fruits);

print_r($fruits);
```

The other option would be to return the modified array, doing something like this:

```
function add_fruit($ar) {
    $ar[] = 'oranges';
    return $ar;
}

$fruits = [
    '0' => 'apples',
    '1' => 'pears',
    '2' => 'bananas',
];

$fruits = add_fruit($fruits);

print_r($fruits);
```

Comment: Please if this answer solved your question, consider marking it as the accepted answer, you can also see the second version working [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/29e946c2b9495ba0d622a4d6bed72934b0be6a55).

Comment: Yes I will, but I have to wait 4 mins ! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `array_push` if you want to add multiple item, for single item better to use `$array[] =`

```
function add_fruit($ar) {
    array_push($ar, "oranges");
    return $ar;
}

$fruits = [
    '0' => 'apples',
    '1' => 'pears',
    '2' => 'bananas',
];

$fruits  = add_fruit($fruits);

print_r($fruits);
```

Result would be:

> Array (
> [0] => apples
> [1] => pears
> [2] => bananas
> [3] => oranges )

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the parameter By Reference (see [Passing by Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php))

Your code should look like this:

```
function add_fruit(&$ar) {
    $ar[] = 'oranges';
}
```